Why Can CORS Issues Arise When Storing JWT in Cookies, but Not When Using the Authorization Header?
I was reading about JWT on this site(https://jwt.io/introduction) and came across the following statement:
"If the token is sent in the Authorization header, Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) won't be an issue as it doesn't use cookies."
What does this statement mean? I’ve searched around, but aside from setting
 configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);

in Spring when storing JWT in cookies, I couldn't find any other significant differences.
I understand that whether you use cookies or the Authorization header, you still need to configure CORS on the server. Why does the site include this statement? I’m trying to understand the reasoning behind it.

You should ask that question here where the site is maintained.

Cookies are a type of ambient authority; when applicable, it's the browser (not the client, i.e. the JavaScript code) that adds them to the request. Problems arise when adversaries can trick users into sending requests that carry sensitive cookies. In contrast, if a JWT must be added in a header by the client, adversaries have no way (without, say, some XSS or client-side path traversal) of forcing users to include said header in their forged requests.

The main reason why you shouldn't store JWT in cookies is that a malicious actor can trick the user into sending a request along with the cookie's content. (the same issue with HttpOnly cookie, check: OWASP)
To protect user's JWT you should store it in Local Storage that must be also protected from XSS (described below). Then, on each request the client should fetch JWT from the Local Storage and put it into the request Header.
How to protect Local Storage from XSS:

Use the CSP header
Sanitize all user inputs and BE responses. Here are details: XSS cheatsheets

